# Unable to click element using CSS, Class or XPath Locators

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to click a button. I tried the CSS, XPath and ClassName locators. I'm getting a "unknown error: Element is not clickable at point" error

```
WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait (driver, 15);  
 wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#get- 
   quote-enabled > fieldset > a"))).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'Actions' object:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement webelement = By.cssSelector("#get- 
   quote-enabled > fieldset > a");
actions.moveToElement(webelement).click().perform();
```